# Linking two forms together

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, forms

I was wondering if it is possible to persay 'link' two winforms together in C#. In a way that I can just call Variables like: `ApplicationProperties.ApplicationPort.BaudRate` instead of having to make an instance for everything I want to call? Similar to VB.net. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appriciated.

I have two forms(MainBox) and (ApplicationProperties). I would like to have both form accessable from eachother. In a way similar to VB.NET.

Ex:

In form one I have a Serial Port (ApplicationPort), and I am writing the values to a .xml file.

```
    public void SaveApplicationProperties()
    {
        try
        {
            //CreateNode(everything being referenced. Put text boxes, and drop down boxes here.
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\ForteSenderv2.0\Properties.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            //Making the code indeted by 2 characters.
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 2;

            //Making the start element "Table".
            writer.WriteStartElement("Forte_Data_Gatherer_Application");
            //Calling the rst of the .xml file to write.
            CreateNode(ApplicationPort.PortName, ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString(), ApplicationPort.DataBits.ToString(), ApplicationPort.Parity.ToString(), ApplicationPort.StopBits.ToString(), ApplicationPort.Handshake.ToString(), writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ApplicationPort.PortName);
            MessageBox.Show(ApplicationPort.BaudRate.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Writing to .xml file failure: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to be able to call that Serial Port from form two without having to make an instance. I have it working with an instance but I am finding it tedious to creat an instance for every Serial Port, Text Box, or tool that I want to use in form2. Is ther any way I can call them like I would in VB.NEt?

Comment: is one form a parent of the other? or are they completely separate

Comment: I am not entirely sure. I clicked Project >> Add New Windows Form.

Comment: It would really help in expanding your question to include how these forms should interact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of having to make an instance for everything I want to call

If it is an instance method than you will have to create an instance of form If you think that you can make your method static than you can call it the way you want.
e.g

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     new Form2().InstanceMethod(); //Call with instance
     Form2.StaticMethod();   // call without creating instane
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public void InstanceMethod()
    {}
    public static void StaticMethod()
    {}
}
```

Comment: It is more than just methods though. I want to be able to call objects like `MainBox.BaudRateBox.SelectedItem` from the second form.

Comment: Will this let me be able to call like that? So for the dumbfoundedness, I am fairly new.

Comment: @ChaseErnst No you won't be able to call instance objects like BaudRateBox like that. you will have to create an instance of the form

Comment: And I will have to make a instance for every object?

Comment: @ChaseErnst Yes, every object for which you want to call an instance variable, method etc

Comment: I see, well that is what I was trying to avoid. I don't want to do the tedious work of making a method for every combo box on my Form2.

Comment: @ChaseErnst you don't have to create method for every combobox. You can just make them public and they will be accessible via form instance.

Comment: I apologize for being dumb, ahah. I am very new to winforms on C#. 

So let me clarify what you are saying. I can make an instance for From2 from Form1 and vice versa, and then just make all of the objects public. Then I will be able to call them more easily?

Comment: if you want to access properties of Form2 in Form1. then you should only create instance of Form2 in Form1 and then you can access all the public properties of Form2.

Comment: my pleasure. we are here to help.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing for you to look at is using the [ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

Your other next best alternative is the instance class that other answers include.

It would get messy way too quickly to try and have all of your applications forms pass parameters around.

Comment: If I were to use the instance class that others are talking about, how would it get messy? Would it not resemble the way you can call objects in VB.net

Comment: Oh no sorry, it wouldn't get messy at all, I was more referring to passing around references to the forms

Comment: Oh okay. I will look at the link you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your forms inherit from a common base form class, where there you would put your common properties on.

Comment: Is that like a global variable? or different?

Comment: It is object inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot link two form classes together like you are stating, because they are instances and you want to have static methods that deal with the values from two distinct instances, but treat them as one.